# Connect a sidebar input with a ggplotly filter for Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

How can I connect a sidebar input with a ggplotly filter for Flexdashboard

I am using this code but it doesn't work properly.

```
renderUI({
  selectInput("var", "Select a variable:", choices = c("var1", "var2", "var3"))
})
```

```
data <- reactive({
  subset(data, data$var == input$var)
})
```

```
renderPlotly({
  ggplotly(ggplot(data(), aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point())
})
```

Comment: We need more details. Better a working example of your app. Your code looks more or less ok. Can you try `output$myplot <- renderPlotly({ req(input$var) ; 
  ggplotly(ggplot( subset(data, data$var == input$var), aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point())
})`

Comment: selectInput("select_year", 
        label = "Year", 
        choices = c("2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "All"), selected = "All")

Comment: renderPlotly({forums_merged_title_score %>% 
   filter(str_detect(Year, if_else(input$select_year=="All", "", input$select_year))) %>% ggplot(aes(x = score, y = title)) + 
  geom_point(pch = 18, col = "#9A3F7F", size = 3) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + labs(title = "", y = "", x = "")})

Comment: It works like this, but sometimes it doesn't appear in dashboard

Comment: the ggplotly part is missing in your last comment. Have you checked whether the filter is working with all years outside a shiny environment?

Comment: With ggplotly it doesn't appear at all. <shiny.render.function>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Roman, thank you so much for your willingness to help

Comment: selectInput("select_year", 
        label = "Year", 
        choices = c("2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "All"), selected = "All")              
   filterData <- reactive({
  forums_merged_title_score %>% 
    filter(str_detect(Year, if_else(input$select_year=="All", "", input$select_year)))
})
  
 
 renderPlotly({ ggplotly(ggplot(filterData(), aes(x = factor(score), y = title)) + 
  geom_point(pch = 18, col = "#9A3F7F", size = 3) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + labs(title = "", y = "", x = "")  + scale_y_discrete(labels = function(y) str_wrap(y, width = 26)))})

Comment: It works, but every time when I'm running document, sometimes it doesn't appear .
what kind of problem it can be?